# UTF-8 not recognized in SQL batch process through Putty

Tags: batch, putty, database, sql, utf-8

I have an .sql file with a few simple "Insert into" SQL commands that are being inserted into a table called Künstler.

```
insert into Künstler (name) values ('Mariah Carey');
insert into Künstler (name) values ('Michael Jackson');
```

However upon executing the file through Putty to run all these commands, each line is met with an error;

```
During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0007N The following on "insert into K" mark "▒" is invalid.
```

It seems the German umlaut characters are being transformed into '▒'

I have enabled UTF-8 on Putty and the commands will work if entered manually, but not as a batch. Is there any work around?

For extra information, the language I am using is DB2.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, to call the column "Künstler". I would consider, simple to rename the colomn.

Comment: @duDE Yeah I would do the same but unfortunately I don't have a choice in the matter :/

Answer (score 0):

Running a *script* in PuTTY is not affected by any of PuTTY's settings.  It would only depend upon the encoding (character-set) of the script and your locale settings (as well as the database's encoding—and the way it reads scripts).

When you *type* on the keyboard using PuTTY, that depends on PuTTY's settings for the keyboard.

Rather than look for a fix in PuTTY, you might be able to set your application code page (mentioned in the [DB2 reference](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/ps/products/db2/info/vr7/pdf/letter/db2s0e71.pdf)) to UTF-8 (page 1208 according to [Understanding DB2 Universal Database character conversion](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506chong/)).  According to [Derivation of code page values](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006825.html), that *should* happen automatically if your locale is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution turned out to be rather simple. I was writing the script in notepad++ and I had set the file to the wrong encoding. Switching the encoding from the default ANSI to UTF-8 solved the issue.

This can be done through Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM.